# Analyzing elements in tables in lua_State calls

Tags: c, lua

So I'm trying to write a program for lua and irrlicht, and currently I am making a function for creating a mesh (in this case, a simple triangle) that is callable in real time from the command line.

For example, while the program is running, if I write "addMesh({{0,0,0}, {5,0,0}, {0,0,5}})" in the command line, a triangle will be made with it's corners at those three coordinates.

Now, I know how to make functions that can be called from the command line and such, that's not what my issue is. My issue is this:

```
int addMesh(lua_State* L){
    luaL_checkType(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);
}
```

As far as I've been taught so far, if you want to (for example) if the first argument sent in is a table, you can use luaL_checktype( L, 1, LUA_TTABLE ). Well, in the example this would be true. But how can I access the data in the able, like any of the three vertices that are in it?

I need to access them and analyze their data so that I can create a simple mesh from them, after all. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After you check it is a actually a table, you can traverse it with functions like `lua_gettable`, `lua_rawget` etc.

[Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/27.1.html) is a good starting point, other long-lasting resources like [lua-users](http://lua-users.org/wiki/) might also provide useful examples.

Also, the reference manual for your version of the language will become your best friend once you start writing C code around Lua. You can [find it](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/) on the official Lua web site.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hints ^^ I've been playing around a bit, and I can successfully access members of an array when sent through a lua_state. However, the issue is still when there's a table within a table (as in the example, where I have three tables within the table that I'm sending to the function). i don't know how to access these. Or rather, I might be able to access those in the similar way as I access the ints when not having any nestled tables, but then I don't know how to access the elements in the arrays that are in the big array. Do you got any more pointers?

Comment: @JensLomander lua_rawget if you can access elements of the array, then you can check if an element is a table and apply rawget to it as well :)